# mongoDB - querying on a query result

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

i'm sure there must be a way to do this, but being fairly new on mongo, it's quite puzzling for me to find the correct way.

Suppose we have a document in our db that has this layout:

```
{
  location:{
            type:"Polygon",
            coordinates: [
                          [
                           [-180,-90],
                           [-90, -90],
                           [-90, -45],
                           [-180,-45],
                           [-180,-90]
                          ]
                         ]
           }
  inner_locations:[
                   { type:"Polygon",
                     coordinates:"--polygon fully contained in the location polygon--"
                   }
                   { type:"Polygon",
                     coordinates:"--polygon fully contained in the location polygon--"
                   }
                   { type:"Polygon",
                     coordinates:"--polygon fully contained in the location polygon--"
                   }
                ]
```

for the sake of the argument let's suppose that the location marks a neighborhood on a map and the inner_locations the buildings in it.
Now let's suppose that i have a polygon and i want to find all the documents (neighborhoods) that intersect it. the task is easy: i just go with:

```
db.name.find({location:
                       {$geointersect:
                                      {$geometry:
                                                { "type":"Polygon",                   
                                                   "coordinates": [[...]]
                                                }
                                      }
                        }
              })
```

now let's suppose further i want to know how the individual buildings of the neighborhood intersect that polygon, how could i do that ?
the result of the query is an array of objects so i was thinking maybe there was a way to pipeline the first query to a second one using the output array as input ? or pheraps there is a way to use a similar query on the projection document of the first query to obtain the wanted result ? any help would be much appreciated for this fellow mongo user :)